# Crossbrowser solution for chaining jQuery after .remove()

Tags: jquery, dom, chain

**After removing** a DOM element with `.remove()` or some similar method, I would like to **chain further** and reach DOM nodes from the location I was at.

Example:

```
$(SELECTOR).children().first().remove().parents(SELECTOR1).doSomething().andSoOn()
```

**UPDATE:**

I would like a method that works on every modern browser, and IE from 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i get it, use [end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/):

```
$(SELECTOR).children().first().remove().end().parents(SELECTOR1).doSomething().andSoOn()
```

Comment: Wow, I've literally never even heard of `end()`. Nice find. Although what if `$(SELECTOR)` is one of the parents that matches `SELECTOR1`?

Comment: Do You consider this method as a faster way, than the one suggested by @Dhaval Marthak with the `.add()` method?

Comment: @StevenPalinkas http://jsperf.com/ But this method is not the same as the one used by Dhaval Marthak

Comment: @A.Wolff this is true... but you could also do something like `$(SELECTOR).children().first().remove().end().parents().addBack().filter(SELECTOR1).doSomething().andSoOn()`

Answer (score 2):

You can't move further after element is removed but you can try this:

```
$(SELECTOR).children().first().remove().add($(SELECTOR))
      .parents(SELECTOR1).doSomething().andSoOn()
```

you can use [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) which constructs a new jQuery object from the union of those elements and the ones passed into the method.

That means after removing the first child of the current selector's children it will add current selector again and will further look for the selector in `.parents(selector1)` and you can do further processing on the one of the parents' selector and do so on.

Comment: Could You - please - provide some explanation?

Comment: What if `$(SELECTOR)` is one of the parents?

Comment: @AdamMerrifield It depends since OP is not clear with the parents of the current selector!

Comment: Do You consider this method as a faster way, than the one suggested by @A. Wolff with the `.end()` ?

Comment: It appears you're missing a `)` in your answer also.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessary to **have to** chain this method. Just set it to a variable first that way you can do whatever you want to it after it's gone.

```
var $remove = $(SELECTOR).children().first(),
    $parents = $remove.parents(SELECTOR1);
$remove.remove();
$parents.doSomething().andSoOn();
```

Comment: Is there no way to store the place of the deleted Node on the DOM tree, instead of storing the Nodes themselves in variables?

Comment: @StevenPalinkas There is, with [`index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) but I don't see why you would want to do that. It would be slower because you would have to re acquire the element based off an index after. There is absolutely nothing wrong with storing element as variables. It is very fast also.

Comment: Yes, @Adam, it might be, but it is not strictly related to my question. :)

Comment: @StevenPalinkas Just so you know, like I said using variables is [much much faster](http://jsperf.com/variable-vs-chaining2).

Answer (score 0):

if your line does not work, it is not possible to get the parents of a non-existing element (sounds pretty logical actually...)

```
var $child = $(SELECTOR).children().first(),
    $parents = $child.parents(SELECTOR1);
$child.remove();
$parents.doSomething().andSoOn()
```

solves the problem.